Automated Elastic Beanstalk deployment of dotnet application fails on both CodePipeline and GitHub Actions, but works manually
I'm trying to set up automated deployment of my .NET Core API application to an existing EB environment. I'm currently deploying manually via the AWS Toolkit (Publish to AWS) extension for Visual Studio, which works completely fine. But every time I try to set up seemingly any CI/CD pipeline, I get this exact same ERROR message after the "Added instance [i-0adf163e55a825fa9] to your environment." stage:
06:10:39 ERROR: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed
06:10:44 ERROR: [Instance: i-0adf163e55a825fa9 ConfigSet: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PostInit, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy, Infra-WriteVersionOnStartup] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null.
06:10:44 INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
06:10:44 ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0adf163e55a825fa9'. Aborting the operation.
06:10:44 ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
06:10:45 ERROR: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: v-638557011188113073, Health: Yellow, Health Status: Warning

I've tried looking at the last 100 lines of logs in the EB dashboard, as well as comb through my S3 bucket, but nothing in those logs match up with the date and time of when I receive the error messages (trying to take timezones into account too). I think I've gone through 12 different guides on how to setup a pipeline specifically for ASP.NET Core applications and they've all failed, mostly because they're all outdated and do not match with AWS' current interface. What am I missing?
GitHub Workflow file:
name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-2019
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'

      - name: Build and Publish
        working-directory: ./API
        run: dotnet restore && dotnet publish -c Release -o publish --self-contained "true"

      - name: Create Deployment Package
        uses: thedoctor0/zip-release@0.7.6
        with:
          type: 'zip'
          filename: 'API.zip'
          path: |
            API\publish

      - name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v22
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: AppName
          environment_name: EnvironmentName
          version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
          region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          deployment_package: API.zip

--EDIT:
As Delta George suggested, I tried deploying through AWS CLI. It's worth mentioning that my API project is located in my repo as a separate folder inside of my overall repository. My project structure looks therefore as follows:
Repo  
│
└── API
│   │   API.csproj
|   |   API.sln
│   │   appsettings.json
|   |   aws-beanstalk-tools-defaults.json
|   |   web.config
|   |   etc.
│
└── Frontend project

With that in mind, I ran the following commands individually to try an deploy my API project to my EB environment using AWS CLI (v2):
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish

cd .\publish\

zip -r ../API.zip *

cd ..

aws s3 cp API.zip s3://my-s3-bucket-name/Backend/

aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name EBAppName --version-label 1234567890 --source-bundle S3Bucket="my-s3-bucket-name",S3Key="Backend/API.zip"

aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name EBAppNameEnv --version-label 1234567890

All commands run successfully. But checking the EB "events" output during deployment, I can eventually see the same handful of error messages show up as mentioned at the top of this post.

I managed to solve my issue, but not quite the way I originally intended.
Until someone wants me to elaborate, I'm just gonna give a short answer here, since it seems like I was the only one in the world with this specific problem:
After literally 80 different workflow commits and zero solutions on this issue online, I finally gave in to the evil gremlins and made the switch.
I ended up creating a new EC2 application and EB environment - this time running on Linux 2023/3.1.3 instead of Windows 2019/2.15.2. After then updating my workflow, I finally got useful error messages that allowed me to make it all deploy and run successfully. Thank you Linux!
Here is my final workflow:
name: Deploy API to Elastic Beanstalk
 on:
   push:
     branches: ['master']
     paths: ['API/**']

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./API
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'

      - name: Publish .NET project
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o publish --self-contained false

      - name: Zip the contents of the publish folder
        run: cd publish && zip -r ../API.zip .

      - name: Deploy API.zip to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v22
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: LinuxAppName
          environment_name: LinuxEnvName
          version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
          region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          deployment_package: API/API.zip


Are you sure that the access and secret keys are setup correctly and have not expired? Is the AWS_REGION correct? Does the principal represented by these keys have AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier and  AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy policies attached as per this
You mentioned AWS Toolkit extension to Visual Studio. Have you tried deploying with AWS CLI?

Yes, I've double-checked region, access and secret keys are 100% correct. The fact that I am able to successfully deploy via the AWS Toolkit for VS, but not via a simple CI/CD leaves me truly puzzled. I have not tried deploying via AWS CLI yet, no. What exactly do you suggest?


I have also added the two policies to my account as per the Beanstalk Deploy Action instructions.


AWS Toolkit may be passing extra config to EB. Using aws CLI is one way to find what is required

I just tried using AWS CLI and I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Using AWS CLI I'm able to run the commands for uploading zip file to S3 bucket, create-application-version and update-environment. But even then, after my EB says INFO Added instance [i-0805baef607036886] to your environment. I get the same stupid "Command hooks failed" error message.

Pleased post commands you used with AWS CLI.

Please see my updated question that now includes the AWS CLI commands I ran.
